# jQuery Ajax Options - I need advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I working on jQuery ajax, I always think about it's option "async", I know what the meaning this (asynchronous JavaScript and XML), but sometimes I need ajax before statement complete, for example form validations, when I check in db, if username is exists, I always add   in ajax option "async: false". Is a bad way to do this? I need youd advice :)

My Code:

```
var content = $("#content");

function ajaxResponse()
{
    var r = null;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'data.html',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            r = data;
        }
    });
    return r;
}

setInterval(function(){ 
    content.text(ajaxResponse());
},1000);
```

Comment: Whats is your exact issue ?

Comment: That depends on exactly what you're doing. We can't help you without a specific problem.

Comment: In general: Yes it is.

Comment: If you are using `async: false`, you are usually doing something wrong.  You should be processing the data in the callback.

Comment: Issue please. Please clarify your question

Comment: The problem is that you *cannot* return from an AJAX call.  It doesn't work that way.  Or, rather, it's not supposed to work that way.  You should be setting `content.text()` inside the callback.

Comment: Your example is not optimal. you can better call the ajaxresponse in the success of the call.

Comment: Basically, if you use the right approach, both ways can lead to success. With `async=false`the statements following the ajax call will only be executed once this call has finished. In the other case you would have to place the statements in the `success`-function of the ajax call.

Comment: I want ajax result out of the function.

Comment: When I working on validation forms, I need variable that I will can compare if is true or false, but this if statement I need out of the function.

For example:
`var i = $('input');
function ajaxResponse()
{
    var r = null;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check.php',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            r = data;
        }
    });
    return r;
}
var result = null;
if (i == '') result = 'empty';
else if (ajaxResponse() == true) result = 'exists';
else result = 'success!';
console.log(result);`

Comment: @Developer9621: You need to do that comparison *inside* the callback.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: And if I make this comparison out of the function, using "async:false"? Why I can't do this, I tried this way and it's worked!

Comment: @Developer9621: `async:false` might work, but it's highly discouraged.  It will lock up the browser until the AJAX call is complete.  To the user, it might seem like their browser has frozen/crashed.  That's never good.  AJAX is asynchronous, it's better to learn to do it the "right" way.

Comment: Everybody thank's for important answers, I undertood and I will write code in really aynchronous, thank's a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would code that except I would not post to an html page but LOAD an html page instead

```
var content = $("#content"), tId;

function ajaxResponse() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'data.php',
        success: function(data) {
            content.text(data);
            tId = setTimeout(ajaxResponse,1000); // run again
        }
    });
}
```

to update content with an html page:

```
content.load("somepage.html");
```

Comment: Just out of interest, would this code not lead to a continuous recursion (one call per second, so the number of recursion levels will - admittedly - not suddenly explode, but steadily grow)?

Comment: Yes, just like the setInterval in the example I took it from, however if the RESPONSE too more than a second, my code is safer than the setInterval which is not waiting for the result

Comment: I was not complaining, just trying to learn ... ;-) Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do client side validation using ajax then maybe you should consider making both:

- disable the submit button
- the ajax call asynchronously

Then once the ajax callback is fired, if the validation succeeded, you could enable the submit button. It the validation failed you could then display the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax async:

```
function ajaxResponse()
{
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'data.html',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        r = data;   //code here will not be run until the ajax request is complete
    }
  });
}


// script will pause here until ajax request is complete if async is true;
```

Comment: @mplungjan the comments explain the usage of the async property